# Nested JSON in .NET

Tags: c#, json.net

Trying to get address and its value to be curly brackets. means json object within a json object.

```
var jsonObject = new JObject();
dynamic j_obj = new JObject();

j_obj.jsonrpc = "1.0";
j_obj.id = "abc";
j_obj.method = "getrawtransaction";

j_obj.@params = new JArray() as dynamic;

dynamic info = new JObject();
info.txid = "myid";
info.vout = "0";
j_obj.@params.Add(info);

var address = "myaddress";
j_obj.Add(new JProperty(address, "0.01"));

Console.WriteLine(j_obj.ToString());
```

What I want is "address" and its value to be json object.
This is the output I am getting now. 
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu5wP.png)

Comment: It would help if you included your actual JSON

Comment: Please copy the *text* of your output into the question.  Don't include a screenshot of text.

Comment: *"What I want is "address" and its value to be json object."* - So, make it an object instead of a value.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a value property here

```
var address = "myaddress";
j_obj.Add(new JProperty(address, "0.01"));
```

Instead create an object for the address then use that in the property:

```
dynamic addressItem = new JObject();
addressItem.line1 = "foo";

var address = "myaddress";
j_obj.Add(new JProperty(address, addressItem));
```

Alternatively, as you have gone down the dynamics route you could do this

```
j_obj.myaddress = new
{
    line1 = "foo"
}
```

Either of these would create JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    ...
    "myaddress": { "line1": "foo" }
    ...
}
```